laravel problem running background job in php
I have the following job:
    public function handle(): void
    {
        //
        sleep(5);
        echo "hello!";
    }

Following controller:
    public function index() {
        ProcessPodcast::dispatch();
        // return redirect('/api');
        echo "finished!";
    }

and route:
Route::get("/job", [JobTest::class, 'index']);

My problem is basically that the job is not executed in the background as expected. I used the command php artisan queue:work and accessed the /job route that triggers this job, and what happens is that the page takes 5 seconds to be displayed because of sleep(5), but what I expected is that this delay would not occur and it would only be executed in the background.
I'm trying to use redis for this:
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis

No error is displayed to me in the terminal, does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

It probably is, but an echo is sent to output. For webpages, it goes to the screen, but the job becomes a background process, so there is no output device for it, really. Try using Log::info('hello'); instead, which will write to a file in storage/logs

is everything connected per the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#driver-prerequisites

@admcfajn I followed the tutorial to the letter and also downloaded the supervisor, but it didn't work as expected. No error log is issued in the supervisor.

@aynber Thanks for the reply! I added the error log but I still can't identify the problem.

Not intimately familiar with laravel, but are you certain that the job is dispatched as a background task, and not simply an asynchronous task that is implicitly expected to return a value to the application? The latter would explain the wait.

@Sammitch From what I saw, to be executed synchronously, in the environment variables we would have to have a "QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync" but I changed it to redis, so it should work asynchronously.

Again, "asynchronous" does not necessarily mean the same thing as "background". The latter would be explicitly decoupled from the running context, while the former may maintain something akin to a Promise that expects to be fulfilled before the application can complete and allow the page to be rendered.

@Sammitch In the context of php + laravel it would be in the background.

I discovered the problem. It was simply that the information in my .env file was being ignored, so the value for QUEUE_CONNECTION was still being "synced".
Clearing the cache solved it for me:
php artisan config:clear
